# Unix script in informatica post command task

Tags: unix, informatica

I write script to find the particular filename in a folder and copy the files after loaded into target table using informatica.
 I use this script in informatica post command task but my session got failed it did not loaded into target tables but copy the files to backup directory.

cd /etl_mbl/SrcFiles/MainFiles
for f in *Test*.csv
do
   cp -v "$f" /etl_mbl/SrcFiles/Backup/"${f%.csv}"
done

I want to correct my script based on the source files loaded into target using informatica and copy the loaded files into backup directory.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a separate command task. Use informatica's `Post session success command` and `Post session failure command` to achieve this. Put your unix code in `Post session success command` so it will only be triggered after session is successful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go with @Utsav's approach. Alternatively you can use a condition `$YourSessionName.Status = SUCCEEDED` on your link between Session and Command Taks
The benefit of this approach is that the command is clearly visible at the first glance.